# How do I install two different versions of Kdenlive?

Tags: software-installation, versions, kdenlive

My current version of Kdenlive is 15.12.3, 
when I tried to do the rotoscoping effect it
did not work, so I searched and found an answer, 
that the rotoscoping effect is disabled until further.

So, I decided to keep the version, which I have but 
to install another version additionally.

However, when I type:

```
apt-get install kdenlive
```

I have no possibility to choose a version and apt-get
reminds me of the version I have.

So, I do not if the answer is for each program different or can be
applied univerally.

**Is it possible to have two different versions of the same program?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, however you will have to install it manually through a source tarball or git clone. It will not be possible to simply input `sudo apt install kdenlive` and download an alternative version, because only one version is available at a time in the repos (for good reason; look up `slapt-get` for Slackware).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way would be getting the cross-platform AppImage, Kdenlive offers one.

Go to https://kdenlive.org/download/

And get the latest version as an Appimage, download it and mark it executable with

```
chmod +x Kdenlive-*.AppImage
```

Then you can run it from that, as in

```
./Kdenlive-*.AppImage
```

AppImages do not install (it's bundled with all dependencies needed), so you can use it from that without conflicting with your installed version of Kdenlive.